# Python library for rendering HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

Is there any python module for rendering a HTML page with javascript and get back a DOM object?

I want to parse a page which generates almost all of its content using javascript.

Comment: could you retitle the question to something like "emulating a browser DOM in python" - the current one doesn't really reflect the question.

Comment: When you say "dom" object, do you mean a html string containing the HTML from which a DOM would be constructed?

Answer (score 9):

The big complication here is emulating the full browser environment outside of a browser. You can use stand-alone javascript interpreters like *Rhino* and *SpiderMonkey* to run javascript code, but they don't provide a complete browser-like environment to fully render a web page.

If I needed to solve a problem like this I would first look at how the *javascript* is rendering the page, it's quite possible it's fetching data via AJAX and using that to render the page.

I could then use *Python libraries* like [simplejson](/questions/tagged/simplejson) and [httplib2](/questions/tagged/httplib2) to directly fetch the data and use that, negating the need to access the DOM object. However, that's only one possible situation, I don't know the exact problem you are solving.

Other options include the selenium one mentioned by @Łukasz, some kind of:

- WebKit embedded craziness,
- IE win32 scripting craziness or,
- a pyxpcom-based solution (with added craziness) finally.

All these have the drawback of requiring pretty much a fully running web browser for Python to play with, which might not be an option depending on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [python-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) for it.  Requires a running glib and GTK, but that's probably less problematic than wrapping the parts of webkit without glib.

I don't know if it does everything you need, but I guess you should give it a try.

Comment: I think pywebkitgtk can only render the html page. Is it possible to get the xml source after rendering it? There isn't enough docs on that