# Python - render HTML content to GIF image

Tags: python, html, gif

How can I render HTML content to GIF image?

I found how to render it to PDF using reportlab, but no luck with GIF.

I want something like xhtml2pdf.com but final result should be not in pdf, but in image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a similar SO question, [Python library for rendering HTML and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126131/python-library-for-rendering-html-and-javascript) , but I'm not sure the answers are satisfying.

I might try two-stage rendering: HTML -> pdf -> gif.  In that case, reportlab gets you pdf, and PythonMagick (http://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick) can convert the pdf to GIF.