# Image Attachment in python SDK

Tags: python, couchbase

I have the below document which got synced from couchbase lite (iOS).

```
        {

        "Date": "00170925591601",
        "ID": "tmp652844",
        "InvoiceNumber": "tmp652844",
        "Supplier": "Temp",
        "_attachments": {
                        "ImageAttachment": {
                                            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
                                            "digest": "sha1-8uKi9mywFwvoP8qNrTGEMWemgKU=",
                                            "length": 1898952,
                                            "revpos": 2,
                                            "stub": true
                                            }
                        },
        "channels": [
                     "payment"
                    ],
        "type": "invoice"
       }
```

How do I get the attachment from the document? I need to render the image attachment in the HTML. I believe the above attachment data is only meta data.
It would be of great help if someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do I get the attachment from the document?
- this is a default dict with nested dicts and list inside it, you need a nested iterator function or a [recursive method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507206/python-recommended-way-to-walk-complex-dictionary-structures-imported-from-json)...

Comment: I can iterate through the dictionary. That is not a problem. My question is how do I render the image in html? I'm using python SDK.

Comment: sry, but "How do I get the attachment from the document?" was the question for me...."webkit2png" would help you more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633828/html-to-image-in-python

Answer (score 0):

use the function ..

get_attachment(id_or_doc, filename, default=None)
Return an attachment from the specified doc id and filename.

Parameters: 
id_or_doc – either a document ID or a dictionary or Document object representing the document that the attachment belongs to
filename – the name of the attachment file
default – default value to return when the document or attachment is not found
Returns:
a file-like object with read and close methods, or the value of the default argument if the attachment is not found
Since:
0.4.1

check https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.get_attachment for more details

Comment: This documentation leads to CouchDB and not couchbase. Let me know if you find the same for couchbase.