# How to format and print Dash dashboard to PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, plotly-dash

I've just created a dashboard in Dash, which fits automatically to my computer monitor and looks half decent. I now have the problem that I have to produce a way to print to PDF.

I've seen the Vanguard example which uses external CSS to format into an A4-size, and then a print button (using external javascript?). Is there a more 'Dash-native' way of doing this that doesn't require me to learn another programming language (I only know Python)?

There doesn't seem to be anything on the Dash User Guide https://dash.plot.ly/, all I've found is this https://plot.ly/python/pdf-reports/ which describes how to print individual plotly figures to pdf.

Ideally, it would format as it is now online (online layout) without losing space down the sides, and then I could use another layout (pdf layout) which could be printed out.

Any links or suggestions on how to proceed with this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get pdf from plotly if save plot as png image (the most left option on image):
[image: Look at here]

And then using that code convert png to pdf:

```
from PIL import Image
# Save your plot as png file (option "Download as png" in upper-left corner)
PNG_FILE = 'horizontal-bar.png'
PDF_FILE = 'horizontal-bar.pdf'

rgba = Image.open(PNG_FILE)
rgb = Image.new('RGB', rgba.size, (255, 255, 255))  # white background
rgb.paste(rgba, mask=rgba.split()[3])               # paste using alpha channel as mask
rgb.save(PDF_FILE, 'PDF', resolution=100.0)
```

If you are a lazy one, you can use library webkit2png [check here how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633828/convert-html-to-an-image-in-python). This allowing you not clicking on Download as png button and just convert from html to png and then to pdf.

Comment: Including a raster based PNG in a PDF is not the same as turning a SVG rendered vector image into a vector based PDF.