# Is there a Python script or lib for translating html code to a png file with transparent background?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, image-processing, png

Is there a Python script or lib for translating html code to a png file with transparent background?

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body style='width:895px; height: 74px;'>
    <p style='color:#000;font-size:70px;text-align:right;font-family:Microsoft YaHei;line-height:1;letter-spacing:1px'>
        <span>our love</span>
    </p>
    <p style='color:#000;font-size:70px;text-align:right;font-family:Microsoft YaHei;line-height:1;letter-spacing:1px'>
        <span>our love aaa</span>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean rendering HTML and outputting that as a PNG?

Comment: This should work [Convert HTML string to an image in Python [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48537053/11472248)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Let me try if your recommendation can meet my needs.

Comment: Try to use this tool: https://carbon.now.sh/