# Is there a way to save highcharts output as png instead of html

Tags: python, highcharts

I was looking at the following python library:
[Link here](https://github.com/kyper-data/python-highcharts)

I don't think it has the capability of saving the output as .png or .jpeg.

I surfed on google a lot, Could someone Please give me some pointers on how to do it?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: You can convert the html output to an image. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159367/python-render-html-content-to-gif-image) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192799/html-to-image-in-javascript-or-python)

Comment: You can use a server rendering with the use of phantomjs - see those sections http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the highcharts package does not offer that functionality. You could either edit their code, or look into a package that converts html to png. For example https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png

You can call this package from python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("python scripts/webkit2png -h", shell=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to open browser as this will be done in linux machine and I don't have a browser. 
Plus the screenshot does add the pic but also has additional black block in the end.

Comment: webkit2png does not require a browser. Edited my post.

Comment: dumb question, how do I add it in my python script?

    `import webkit2png

    webkit2png("path to the html")`

Comment: Its a separate program. See the snippet in my answer :)

Comment: [Here is the link of the error](https://snag.gy/fTgCrE.jpg)

Tutorial followed:
[Tutorial Link](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/)

Comment: Sorry, was using the standard webkit2png version :) edited my code. Did you install web2kit with pip?

Comment: Yes, I installed it using pip, pip install web2kit

Comment: It is not able to find the script,
[link](https://snag.gy/g8nvmH.jpg)

The reason could be because I installed it via pip?