# Can I use Python to run html

Tags: python, html

i am writing an HTML editor and would like to make a section so that you can view how it would look in web browser directly in the program is this possible?

Thanks so much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python library for rendering HTML and javascript ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126131/python-library-for-rendering-html-and-javascript)

Comment: It is commom sense in forums to search for similar questions in the forum before triggering a new thread.

Comment: Rendering also differs per-browser. So you would first have to define which browser rendering you want to see. Though honestly modern browsers only differ in advanced javascript and CSS rendering.

Comment: First off, I agree with Dave and Rich Bradshaw, hence the +1.Secondly I am embarrassed and ashamed by the fact that people can make such grammatical errors. For example no capital letters at the beginning of sentences, and the fact that you go straight from a statement of fact to a question without any punctuation in between. For example you go straight from "i am writing an HTML editor and would like to make a section so that you can view how it would look in web browser directly in the program" to "is this possible?". One is a statement, the other a question (hence the question mark).

Comment: @extraneon: What about the change from HTML 4 - 5? Doesnt that count as a differentiation in modern browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this - your renderer will quickly differ from real browsers.

Comment: Not really. You can have, on Windows, probably a COM interface to IE, and there is a Webkit binding for Python as well. So you can in theory just embed a real browser :)

Comment: That is two browsers (or versions of)... and the COM interface for IE, if I understand you correctly, will be for ONE version. Currently there are 3 versions commonly supported by websites - 6, 7 and 8. For Firefox there is 2 and 3 (and 3.5 / 3.6 if you count them as versions too), Opera there is 8, 9 and 10 and god knows how many more other browsers. In the time it takes to cover all browsers, something like 5 more browsers or versions of browsers would have been released, making your application out of date. Not good news for developers who like to keep in date.