# Html element position in Python

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm using lxml.html for some html parsing in python.  I'd like to get a rough estimate of the location of elements within the page after it would be rendered by a browser.  It does not have to be exact, but generally correct.  For simplicity I will ignore the effects of Javascript on element location.  As an end result, I would like to be able to iterate over the elements (e.g., via lxml) and find their x/y coordinates.  Any thoughts on how to do this?  I don't need to stay with lxml and am happy to try other libraries.

Comment: You will need a HTML rendering engine to get this information.  A parser won't help.

Comment: You'll also need to consider the effect of CSS. Very little content is rendered without it, these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyQt with webkit:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class MyWebView(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        QObject.connect(self,SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'),self.showelements)

    def showelements(self):
        html=self.page().currentFrame().documentElement()
        for link in html.findAll('a'):
            print(link.toInnerXml(),str(link.geometry())[18:])


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    web = MyWebView()
    web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
    web.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  Is there a way to get this to be a little more command-line friendly, specifically quitting on its own (or operating on sequence of urls?  I have removed 'web.show()' and placed a 'sys.exit(0)' at the end of show elements.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Sven, you need an HTML rendering engine. A question on rendering HTML was asked before, you could refer to that.

[Python library for rendering HTML and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126131/python-library-for-rendering-html-and-javascript)