# Python Get on a website and running $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, python

I am doing some testing on my site, and  I have a python program which does gets on few different pages. Some of these pages have `$(document).ready(function()`. I noticed that when I do get through python, I get the code, but for example `$(document).ready(function()` doesn't run.

How can I run the `$(document).ready(function()` of the site I am doing a GET on?

Thank you for help.

Comment: what are you using to do GET? see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622870/using-urllib2-to-execute-url-and-return-rendered-html-output-not-the-html-itsel

Comment: if you can use node.js instead of python you could use PhantomJS which is a headless browser.

Comment: Related: [Headless Browser for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required), [Screen Scraping a Javascript based webpage in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183682/screen-scraping-a-javascript-based-webpage-in-python), [Screen scraping with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190502/screen-scraping-with-python)

Comment: headless browser! that's what I should have searched for, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), it lets you control a real browser from your python code . That means your javascript will be executed by the browser .

Example code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```