# Load webpage in Python GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface

I've searched on Google and StackOverflow but am having trouble finding the answer, even though it seems like it should be easy to do.

How can I use Python to load a URL into its own window, rather than in a browser? I imagine this should be trivial in Tkinter or some other GUI package.

Comment: [This seems relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126131/python-library-for-rendering-html-and-javascript#126250)

Comment: Ive done this using the ie driver + wxHTMLWindow +wxPython ... but it only handles html4.0 (and im not sure about js)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah. that's very easy with QWebView in PyQt/PySide

You basically instantiate a new QWebView and pass the url to it

```
QWebView.load(QUrl('http://www.www.pythoncentral.io'))
```

you can read more here

http://pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-qwebview/

and also in the pyQt docs

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html

Comment: I believe QWebView is quite expensive, as you need a special license to use their product with that module. They have free versions, but the one that includes QWebView is $500/month. It's insane.

Answer (score 4):

A new option would be: **pywebview**

> pywebview is a lightweight cross-platform wrapper around a webview
>   component that allows to display HTML content in its own native GUI
>   window. It gives you power of web technologies in your desktop
>   application, hiding the fact that GUI is browser based.

See here:
https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - the only problem is not being able to embed a pywebview window, into a GUI, since it is its own window.