# Use local headless browser for proxy in linux

Tags: linux, proxy, headless-browser

Is there a way to use a headless browser like Chrome, Firefox, Selenium etc. as a proxy for shell commands like curl or wget?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That the page is not just dumped, rather that JavaScript is being executed that the modified content is being returned. I cannot use a headless browser directly though. I need the headless browser acting like a proxy. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126131/python-library-for-rendering-html-and-javascript

Comment: Please read my question! I can not use a headless browser or selenium directly, I need that to work and act like a proxy.